# Refresh token flow in Azure Active Directory with a federated Google user

Tags: azure-active-directory

I have set up an Azure Active Directory tenant with direct federation to Google. Next to that I have a .NET core web application using the OIDC code flow for getting both id_tokens and access and refresh tokens. The access token is used to call my API which is working fine.

Now the problem is whenever I use my refresh_token to get a new access_token I receive a new access_token, but no refresh_token. So I can only refresh once.

I only have this issue when authenticating with my Google account using direct federation. When I authenticate using a tenant native account I can refresh unlimited.

We have two multitenant Azure AD app registrations as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-convert-app-to-be-multi-tenant#multiple-tiers-in-a-single-tenant). One for our single page application and one for our API. In our single page application backend we use the [OpenIdConnect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.openidconnectextensions.addopenidconnect?view=aspnetcore-3.0) middleware to authenticate against Azure AD. Note that we are not using the common endpoint, but the tenant specific endpoint because otherwise direct federation does not work. We can reproduce this issue by intercepting the refresh token in the OnTokenResponseReceived event of the OIDC middleware and initiating the refresh flow as stated [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/azuread-dev/v1-protocols-oauth-code#refreshing-the-access-tokens) (by using Postman for instance). The response is successful, but does only contain an access token, no refresh token.

Is this behavior by design?

Comment: I tried to reproduce a similar scenario using [this sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-desktop-msgraph-v2/tree/master), but could not. Can you provide your environment specific details, the repro steps or fiddler captures?

Comment: I updated my question with an extra section describing our environment and how we can reproduce it.